# Is it true that you can block a magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields

So as the Avengers 4 comes to the movie theater, Thor's hammer is getting popular around the market, where I found one product that claims can stick on a metal surface tightly when wanted. Apparently, it's been done through a magnet, but interesting that the product doesn't require electricity (where most products control when they stick onto the surface).

So there's someone online that took it apart and explained, that by having two metals that both stick on the north and south side of the magnet and isolated by a plastic surface can block the magnetic field (according to the pic below), and while the magnet is turned 90 degrees, the magnetic field will be released.

[image]

(Yellow is metal, and brown is plastic).

The video claims that it's because that magnetic field likes to travel through metal materials compare to others, so you can force the field (line) travel through the metal material instead of spreading out by forming a path from the north end to south end of the magnet.

Just curious about how true is it?

Comment: mu metal is the tool of choice when the Meissner effect is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Modulo engineering concerns, the claims are perfectly fine.

However, the disadvantage is that if you want it to be hard to move the hammer when it's attached to something in the "on" state, then it *also* has to be extremely hard to rotate the magnet in that situation to the "off" state, because both actions will cost a similarly large energy. Similarly, whenever the hammer is brought near a metal object, even in the "off" state, the magnet will be automatically pulled to the "on" state. This probably makes it less elegant than an electromagnet-based solution.

Comment: Why it'll automatically pulled to the "on" state?

Comment: @Andrew.Wolphoe Because the energy in that state is lowered. If you've ever played with magnetic spheres, when they get near metal they will also automatically rotate so their magnetic field goes into the metal.

Comment: But the thing that keeps it in "off" (vertical) state is also made out from metal isn't it?

Comment: Also does the above statement only matches when it directly contact to other metals? Or it also work in situations like when a metal item is close to it? As magnets are forces that aren't restricted by the distance.

Comment: "*it also has to be extremely hard to rotate the magnet in that situation to the "off" state*" I mean think about rotating a rare earth magnet sticks onto the magnet surface, it's not that hard compare to pulling it apart from the surface isn't it? The design above is something like rotating the magnet around the curve of outer metal cover, it's not actually pulling it apart from the metal outer case, so it shouldn't be that hard too. Isn't it?